# An instance of an Excel-VBA form opens with an error, if it was closed from the top right red `X`

Tags: vba, winforms, excel

**Prehistory**

I have read the best practises for creating a form, concerning the fact that one should always refer to an object of the form and not the form itself. Thus, I have decided to build a boiler-plate form for myself.

**The problem**

Everything ran smoothly, until the moment I have decided to close the form with the top right red `X`. It closes ok. But then, when I try to open the form again, I get this runtime error:

[image]

The error is on `objPresenter.Show` (see the code below). Obviously, it does not enter in the `if` above. But the problem is that the closing from the `X` does not work fine. When I close the form from the `End` button, anything works. And even, if I copy the code for the closing from the btnEnd to  `UserForm_QueryClose` it still does not work the same.

**The form**

Thus, I have a `modMain`, `frmMain` and `clsSummaryPresenter`, which all take care of the form. I start the code from `modMain`

My form looks like this:

[image]

It has `btnRun`, `btnExit`, `lblInfo`. The name of the class is `frmMain`.

**The code**

In `frmMain`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event OnRunReport()
Public Event OnExit()

Public Property Get InformationText() As String

    InformationText = lblInfo.Caption

End Property

Public Property Let InformationText(ByVal value As String)

    lblInfo.Caption = value

End Property

Public Property Get InformationCaption() As String

    InformationCaption = Caption

End Property

Public Property Let InformationCaption(ByVal value As String)

    Caption = value

End Property

Private Sub btnRun_Click()

    RaiseEvent OnRunReport

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click()

    RaiseEvent OnExit

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)

    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Hide
        'Even if I change the two lines above with this the error happens:
        'RaiseEvent OnExit
        'However, if I simply write END in stead of those two lines
        'anything works quite ok...
        'but that is a bit brutal.

    End If

End Sub
```

In `clsSummaryPresenter`

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objSummaryForm As frmMain

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set objSummaryForm = New frmMain

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Set objSummaryForm = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub Show()

    If Not objSummaryForm.Visible Then
        objSummaryForm.Show vbModeless
        Call ChangeLabelAndCaption("Press Run to Start", "Starting")
    End If

    With objSummaryForm
        .Top = CLng((Application.Height / 2 + Application.Top) - .Height / 2)
        .Left = CLng((Application.Width / 2 + Application.Left) - .Width / 2)
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub Hide()

    If objSummaryForm.Visible Then objSummaryForm.Hide

End Sub

Public Sub ChangeLabelAndCaption(strLabelInfo As String, strCaption As String)

    objSummaryForm.InformationText = strLabelInfo
    objSummaryForm.InformationCaption = strCaption
    objSummaryForm.Repaint

End Sub

Private Sub objSummaryForm_OnRunReport()

    MainGenerateReport
    Refresh

End Sub

Private Sub objSummaryForm_OnExit()

    Hide

End Sub

Public Sub Refresh()

    With objSummaryForm
        .lblInfo = "Ready"
        .Caption = "Task performed"
    End With

End Sub
```

In `modMain`

```
Option Explicit

Private objPresenter   As clsSummaryPresenter

Public Sub MainGenerateReport()

    objPresenter.ChangeLabelAndCaption "Starting and running...", "Running..."
    GenerateNumbers

End Sub

Public Sub GenerateNumbers()

    Dim lngLong         As Long
    Dim lngLong2        As Long

    tblMain.Cells.Clear

    For lngLong = 1 To 4
        For lngLong2 = 1 To 1
            tblMain.Cells(lngLong, lngLong2) = lngLong * lngLong2
        Next lngLong2
    Next lngLong

End Sub

Public Sub ShowMainForm()

    If (objPresenter Is Nothing) Then
        Set objPresenter = New clsSummaryPresenter
    End If

    objPresenter.Show

End Sub
```

**The question**

Once again, why I cannot close the form with the red `X`? I can substitute the code in `UserForm_QueryClose` with `End` but that is a bit brutal. Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen this error when people have Excel versions that are older and try to do work in Win7 or newer.  I believe it has to do with how the UserForm you are calling is being called.  UserForm1.Show (or similar) should be how the UserForm is called.  Anything else, in the newer Excel versions, has been known to give error 80010007.

Comment: Not sure what gives, but something is wrong. If you remove the Hide code from the Queryclose event, the form closes anyway.

Comment: @Cyril: Never heard of that. I always call userforms by using object variables, never have trouble like you suggest. In any Excel version as of '97 up to and including 2016.

Comment: Try commenting out the line `Set objSummaryForm = Nothing`.  I'm guessing that this is related to your event handling, not the form close.

Comment: @jkpieterse it doesn't only *close*, it *destroys the object* - which means if the form contains state that the calling code needed to use, that state is gone now: that's basically `Unload Me` and leaves the caller with having to check if the form object they created `Is Nothing`, because the form has been allowed to destroy itself. Handling `QueryClose` is specifically meant to prevent that. It's the code that *creates* an object that should be responsible for *destroying* that object. A self-destructing object is a rather annoying thing.

Comment: I copied your form, its controls, the code-behind, the presenter class and the module, ran `ShowMainForm` and closed it with the red "X" button, and got no error - no repro, everything works as expected. Excel 2010 x64. I'd suggest you delete the form and re-create it - *something* might have got corrupted with it. Or try reproducing the problem in a brand new workbook/project.

Comment: @jkpieterse I have only received that on Win7 and Win10, or others who have asked me about that error have received it while using Win7 or Win10.  The fix I've used is to ensure that UserForm#.Show is the command used.  I have seen it on 2003-2013 versions of Excel, only.  The rationalize I can try to stumble through is speculative; this is just how I've circumvented the problem as I've seen it.  I would say I've seen this a handful of times, and not on the computer the code was created on (someone writes a macro/userform and another user runs it).  Hopefully that gives a little more insight.

Comment: @Cyril - That just side-steps the problem.  The mechanics of using the default instance of the form is completely different from holding an instance reference.

Comment: @Mat's Mug It destroys the object indeed. I think this is a VBA bug where the cascade of using a userform from a class this way somehow confuses the compiler. If I use a routine where I instantiate the form from within a sub in a normal module using a module-level object variable for the form all is well. This is the way I work usually. So I guess dumping the intermediate class is the way to go here.

Comment: @Cyril: I use Win 7 64 bit and Excel 2010 32 bit, I replicate the problem of the OP. Using my method (no intermediate class between calling code and form, but using a module or sub level form object variable) I've never encountered this problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I have just recreated the form in a blank Excel 2010, x32 bits. Same error, same place. Can you share your file somewhere e.g. in GitHub?

Comment: @jkpieterse - thanks for the efforts for the replication, indeed! I have flawless experience with `no intermediate class between code and form` for about 4 years, but I have decided to do something new :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - just read your comment and realized something - the error appears when you try to open the form after closing it from the red `x`.

Comment: Ok I get a repro now. The error is an automation error on `If Not objSummaryForm.Visible` in `clsSummaryPresenter.Show`. You get an earlier failure if you change `vbModeless` to `vbModal`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the form's mode from `vbModeless` to `vbModal` gives you an earlier and more informative failure:

[image: run-time error: "automation error; connection to type library or object library for remote process has been lost."]

The problem seems to be because the `Cancel = True` assignment in the `QueryClose` handler, isn't working for some reason.

The signature for the `QueryClose` handler is as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
```

Yours is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
```

You should **never type these handler signatures manually** yourself - instead, use the drop-down in the codepane's top-right corner, and have the VBE generate the handler stubs for you:

[image: QueryClose event in the dropdown]

That way your handler signatures will **always** match the interface they're for.

VBA doesn't really care about parameter names in handlers: the way the runtime matches a handler signature is by matching the parameter indices and their types, against the expected ones. Since both `QueryClose` parameters are `Integer` values, inverting them compiles just fine - except when you set `Cancel = True`, what the runtime sees is that you've assigned `CloseMode = -1` **and left the Cancel parameter alone**.

Which means your form *doesn't* cancel its close, and thus the object gets destroyed every time.

Invert the parameters in your `QueryClose` handler, and everything works perfectly fine and exactly as intended.

Comment: It works now! The swaping of the two integers was really something I have disregarded.

Comment: And yes, using the automatic `QueryClose` with the correct signature is a must do.

Comment: If you're ever in doubt about an event signature, you can use the Object Browser to locate the event, and then copy the signature from the Object Browser's bottom pane. That's particularly useful for events marked as hidden, that will *never* appear in the codepane's drodown.

Comment: Well spotted. I never thought about checking the order of the queryclose arguments. As I NEVER type events myself I just assumed the OP also didn't do that and that hence the event arguments would be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the form like so works just fine for me:

```
Option Explicit
dim mfrmMain as ufMain

Sub ShowMainForm2()
    If ufMain Is Nothing Then
        Set ufMain = New mfrmMain
    End If
    mfrmMain.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? What is ufMain? Is it the `frmMain` blueprint?

Comment: ufMain is the name of the forms desiger object in the VBA Editor.